# Process contextual actions

Tags: android

By default, on enable contextual actions, at left side we can see action DONE.

1) How I can add another action CANCEL?

2) On click action DONE contextual action mode disabled. How I can add some verify before click DONE and if need, cancel this action (on click do not disable action mode)?

3) Can I hide action DONE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How I can add another action CANCEL?

That is not necessary, as the user can just click the BACK button to dismiss the action mode.

> How I can add some verify before click DONE and if need, cancel this action (on click do not disable action mode)?

That is not supported, sorry.

> Can I hide action DONE?

That is not supported, sorry.

It really sounds like an action mode is not the right approach for whatever it is you are attempting to accomplish. You could consider making a separate activity for this particular operation and using the "done" or "done/discard" custom action views that [Roman Nurik wrote about](https://plus.google.com/113735310430199015092/posts/R49wVvcDoEW).